# DRYing up query on a Rails polymorphic assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have polymorphic `likes` model, for storing productions, comments, whatever that people like. Is there a way to dry up this query?

```
user.likes.where(:likeable_id => thing.id, :likeable_type => thing.class)
```

This doesn't work:

```
user.likes.where(:likeable => thing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

class Like
     ...

```
 # scope
 def self.for(object)
   scoped.where(:likeable_id => object.id, :likeable_type => object.class.to_s)
 end
```

end

You would then use it like this:

```
user.likes.for(thing)
```